# Binary tree pruning with BFS

Tags: java, tree

Below the text of the [exercise](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-pruning/):

> We are given the head node root of a binary tree, where additionally
>   every node's value is either a 0 or a 1.
>
> Return the same tree where every subtree (of the given tree) not
>   containing a 1 has been removed.
>
> (Recall that the subtree of a node X is X, plus every node that is a
>   descendant of X.)
>
> Note:
>
> - The binary tree will have at most 100 nodes.
> - The value of each node will only be 0 or 1.

I have the following code and it does not look nice to me as too many if statements strolling around. How can I make this shorter and nice looking (more readable). Tree has nodes that contain 0 or 1 as value. I make the node null if it does not contain any node having 1 as value.

```
public TreeNode pruneTree(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null || (root.left == null && root.right == null && root.val == 0)) return null;

    Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.offer(root);

    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        TreeNode node = queue.poll();

        if (node.left != null && !containsOne(node.left)) {
            node.left = null; 
        }

        if (node.right != null && !containsOne(node.right)) {
            node.right = null; 
        }

        if (node.left != null) {
            queue.offer(node.left);
        }

        if (node.right != null) {
            queue.offer(node.right);
        }
    }

    return root;
}

private boolean containsOne(TreeNode node) {
    if (node == null) return false;
    if (node.val == 1) return true;
    return containsOne(node.left) || containsOne(node.right);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Is this code referring to the exercise [binary tree pruning](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-pruning/) ?

Comment: Please add at the challenge description to the question.

Comment: @dariosicily yes

Comment: I've edited your post adding description of the exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I checked [binary tree pruning](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-pruning/) and the structure of class TreeNode is not modifiable as I expected:

```
public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
}
```

It's possible to shorten your code with constraints of the class, your method `containsOne` is the following:

> ```
> private boolean containsOne(TreeNode node) {
>     if (node == null) return false;
>     if (node.val == 1) return true;
>     return containsOne(node.left) || containsOne(node.right);
> }
> ```

Because the third line will be executed when the condition `node.val == 1` is false put directly this condition in the or expression in the third line:

```
private static boolean containsOne(TreeNode node) {
    if (node == null) return false;
    return node.val == 1 || containsOne(node.left) || containsOne(node.right);
}
```

About your method `PruneTree` you can shorten the following lines inside the method:

> ```
> if (node.left != null && !containsOne(node.left)) {
>     node.left = null; 
> }
> if (node.right != null && !containsOne(node.right)) {
>     node.right = null; 
> }
> if (node.left != null) {
>     queue.offer(node.left);
> }
> if (node.right != null) {
>     queue.offer(node.right);
> }
> ```

The code can be rewritten like below, two equal blocks and not so elegant to see but the original structure in the site cannot be modified, so I haven't thought about other alternatives:

```
if (node.left != null) {
    if (!containsOne(node.left)) { node.left = null; }
    else { queue.offer(node.left); }
}

if (node.right != null) {
    if (!containsOne(node.right)) { node.right = null; }
    else { queue.offer(node.right); }
}
```

I checked the code on the site passing all tests.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your attempt is far too complex and LeetCode.com doesn't notice that :(

The problem is that `containsOne` basically repeats the search for the subtrees that it already has run for in a previous iteration.

Example:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \ 
D   E
```

You start to search tree A which you do by searching subtrees B and C. In order to search B you search subtrees D and E. Then you move on to subtree B and repeat the search there, including repeating the searches on D and E. Next you move to subtree D and repeat the search there a third time, and so on.

Instead by using a recursive so-called [post-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order_(LRN)) where you basically start at the bottom (the leaves) of the tree, where you remove any leaves with the value `0`,  you get a much simpler solution:

```
public TreeNode pruneTree(TreeNode node) {

    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }

    node.left = pruneTree(node.left);
    node.right = pruneTree(node.right);

    if (node.left == null && node.right == null && node.val == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    return node;
}
```